# TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in react and I am playing with an example in `https://jscomplete.com/repl.`

So far my code looks like :

```
let data = [
    {
    name:"Paul O’Shannessy",
    avatar_url:"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/8445?v=4",
        company_name:"Facebook"
  },
  {
    name:"Tom Preston-Werner",
    avatar_url:"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=4",
        company_name:"Facebook"  
  }
];

const Card = (props) => {
    return (
    <div style={{margin:'1em'}}>
        <img width="75" src={props.avatar_url} />
      <div className="info" style={{display: 'inline-block',marginLeft: 10}}>
        <div style={{fontSize: '1.25em',fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{props.name}</div>
        <div>{props.company_name}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const CardList = (props) => {
    return (
    <div>
        {props.cards.map((card) => <Card {...card}/>)}
    </div>
  );
}

class Form extends React.component {
    render() {
    return (
        <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Github Username" />
        <button type="submit">Add Card</button>
      </form>
    );
  };
}

class App extends React.component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Form />
        <CardList cards={data} />
      </div>
    );
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,mountNode);
```

But each time I run, I keep getting this runtime error.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Should be `React.Component` instead of `React.component`

Notice the capital letter.

Comment: In my case, I forgot the '`.`': I wrote `ReactComponent` instead of `React.Component`.

Comment: In my case it was to remove the ().. assuming it's because it's not a function, but a class now :)

Comment: @erayner Man you saved me. How did I miss that?

Answer (score 10):

when you import React then try `React.Component` and never use `React.Component()`. Remove these parentheses, then this error will go.

```
import React from 'react';
......
class App extends React.Component {
}
```

or you can try this.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
......
class App extends Component {
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following was failing:

```
import { AbstractFilter } from './';

export class DismissedFilter extends AbstractFilter {
...
```

where my index was was like:

```
export { AbstractFilter}  from './filter';
```

I was able to resolve by specifying the full path to the import:

```
import { AbstractFilter } from './filter';

export class DismissedFilter extends AbstractFilter {
...
```

Seems the error was somehow related to webpack

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was socket version issue so i do this to solve my issue

```
- npm un socket.io-client
- npm i socket.io-client@4.4.1
- npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably unrelated to this case in particular, but I've been upgrading from `react-css-modules` to `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` and got this same error.
Turns out the `postcss-scss` syntax I had configured, explicitely needed `postcss@8` defined as a dependency in my `package.json`, (that worth to mention, also seems to be an error for libraries like [`stylelint-config-standard-scss`](https://github.com/stylelint-scss/stylelint-config-standard-scss/issues/5#issuecomment-961709882)) so:

```
 yarn add -D postcss@8
```

fixed my problem.